# Using a normal text link instead of a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am writing a small application using Rails 3. In one part of it there is a link (should be a link) that if clicked adds a connection between two people (see below).

What I am really needing is to use a normal text link instead of a form, how is this done?

```
<%= form_for([@profile, @contact]) do |f| %>

    <p><%= f.hidden_field :profile_id, :value => params[:profile_id] %></p>
    <p><%= f.hidden_field :friend_id, :value => profile.id %></p>

    <p><%= f.submit %></p>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
<%= link_to 'link these persons', [@profile, @contact], :method => :post, :profile_id => params[:profile_id], :friend_id => profile.id %>
```

Comment: Ok, this should work: `<%= link_to 'link these persons', profile_contact_path(@profile, @contact, :profile_id => params[:profile_id], :friend_id => profile.id), :method => :post %>

Comment: Sorry, but this one fails also.

Comment: How is it failing? Could you give the html code rendered by this link in your page, and the log of the error you get when you click it?

Comment: The redered HTML-kod is <a href="/profiles/6/contacts" data-method="post" friend_id="6" profile_id="6" rel="nofollow">Add</a>.

Comment: What do you think about this?

Comment: What route is the polymorphic_url[@profile, @contact] supposed to render? Is "/profiles/6/contacts" really the url you try to reach via post? if it is the case, try `profile_contacts_path(@profile, :friend_id => profile.id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sumbitting the form with javascript like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Submit', "#", :onclick=>"('form_id').submit()"%>
```

This will submit your form.